# Deleting a comment (mine) should reset the 30-second rate-limit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, rate-limiting

Post a comment. Notice spelling mistake. Delete comment, fix error, repost.

OOPS! 30-second rate limit! Gaaahh!

Go away and do something else, post the corrected comment when you come back.

This is highly annoying and shouldn't be necessary. If anything I should be encouraged, not hindered, to take the time to fix a small mistake in a comment.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one...

Comment: Me three! Please change it.

Comment: Completed via edit

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Shouldn't this be status-declined, not status-completed? What the OP asked for has not been implemented. what has been implemented is the ability to edit comments, which makes this question moot, but the fact is that this particular scenario is still reproducible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree. This should also be extended to when there happens to be some sort of error that occurs which will not post your comment but still set the 30 second timer.

Answer (score 6):

..Or allow us to edit comments

Answer (score 1):

This could open comments up to greifing though. Someone could submit and delete the same comment repeatedly making it hard to flag.

Having said that I have felt the need for this myself so if it could be implemented safely I'd like to see it.

Comment: That's when you flag the post, pointing out the retard behavior, and let the moderators kick him or her in the square of the ass.

Comment: This concern can easily be alleviated by allowing only one comment deletion per 5 seconds, or only 10 comment deletions per post per hour, or something similarly reasonable. Not being able to edit a comment for 30 seconds is not reasonable.